# Faster way to find neighbors indexes

Tags: java, math, arraylist

I'm creating a minesweeper game and I really need a fast and Efficient way of calculating the neighbors of a mine, Actually im storing my tiles in an Arraylist so I can use them in a gridview, so the position is lineal but the rendering will be a matrix n*n. I have a way to do it but I think someone can have a more efficient way.

What I want to achieve:

```
0 1 1 1
0 1 * 1
0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0
```

So given that matrix having the indexes in a lineal List the position should be the following:

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

So I need an efficient way of obtaining 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12 giving the index 7.

Code to generate bombs:

```
public void plantMines(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    //Used set so we dont get duplicates
    Set<Integer> mineCoords = new LinkedHashSet<>(mDifficulty.mines);
    //First we randomly select all coordenates
    while (mineCoords.size() < mDifficulty.mines){
        Integer coord = rand.nextInt(mListCap) + 1;
        mineCoords.add(coord);
    }
    //Now we can set the mines accordingly
    for (Integer coord: mineCoords){
        mTiles.get(coord).setMine(true);
    }
}
```

Actual code to find neighbors:

```
for (int row = 0; row < ROW_SIZE; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < COL_SIZE; col++) {
            int neighbourBombSize = 0;

            // TOP ROW
            if ((row-1) >= 0 && (col-1) >= 0) {
                if (getTile(row-1, col-1).hasBomb()) {
                    neighbourBombSize++;
                }
            }

            if ((row-1) >= 0) {
                if (getTile(row-1, col).hasBomb()) {
                    neighbourBombSize++;
                }
            }

            if ((row-1) >= 0 && (col+1) < COL_SIZE) {
                if (getTile(row-1, col+1).hasBomb()) {
                    neighbourBombSize++;
                }
            }

            // SAME ROW
            if ((col-1) >= 0) {
                if (getTile(row, col-1).hasBomb()) {
                    neighbourBombSize++;
                }
            }

            if ((col+1) < COL_SIZE) {
                if (getTile(row, col+1).hasBomb()) {
                    neighbourBombSize++;
                }
            }

            // BOTTOM ROW
            if ((row+1) < ROW_SIZE && (col-1) >= 0) {
                if (getTile(row+1, col-1).hasBomb()) {
                    neighbourBombSize++;
                }
            }

            if ((row+1) < ROW_SIZE) {
                if (getTile(row+1, col).hasBomb()) {
                    neighbourBombSize++;
                }
            }

            if ((row+1) < ROW_SIZE && (col+1) < COL_SIZE) {
                if (getTile(row+1, col+1).hasBomb()) {
                    neighbourBombSize++;
                }
            } 

            getTile(row, col).setNeighbourBombSize(neighbourBombSize);
        }
    }
```

Help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: why don't you use 2D array?

Comment: Easier to implement with a GridLayout if its an Array

Comment: You can use 2D array as suggested by @SureshSajja, or you can use Map of List, each map entry (i.e. list) will represent a row and map index will be row number. I personally prefer 2D array.

Comment: I actually just created a minesweeper game not too long ago. What I did was store/access tiles using the formula `x + y * width`. To grab surrounding tiles, grab the current tile using the formula above, then adjust the formula slightly to grab the surrounding tiles: `x + (y-1) * width` to grab the tile above the current tile; `(x + 1) + y * width` to grab the tile on the right of the current tile; `(x - 1) + (y - 1) * width` to grab the tile diagonally from the current tile, ect..

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING** : I've take your code as starting point, but your index start a 1, but in java array index start at 0, so it may not work.

I would do something like that :

```
int neighbourBombSize = 0;
// Compute currentCell row / col
int currentCellCol = ((currentCellIndex - 1) % COL_SIZE) + 1;
int currentCellRow = ((currentCellIndex - 1) / COL_SIZE) + 1;
System.out.println("Neighbors of " + currentCellIndex + " (" + currentCellRow + ", " + currentCellCol + ")");
for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {
    for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
        if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
            continue; // Current cell index
        }
        int neighborCol = currentCellCol + y;
        int neighborRow = currentCellRow + x;
        if (neighborCol > 0 && neighborRow > 0 && neighborCol <= COL_SIZE && neighborRow <= ROW_SIZE ) {
            int computedNeighborIndex = neighborCol + ((neighborRow - 1) * COL_SIZE);
            if (getTile(neighborRow , neighborCol ).hasBomb()) {
                neighbourBombSize++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see a running example (computing neighbors index for all case) here : [Running example](https://ideone.com/Mv4kXS)

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to write the whole game referring to cells using this 1-based linear index?  If so, you will want to isolate the conversion to and from coordinates.  Otherwise you will eventually mess up somewhere.

Try something like this:

```
class Board {

    final int rows;
    final int cols;

    Board(int cols, int rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
    }

    int col(int index) {
        assert index > 0 && index <= rows * cols;
        return (index - 1) % cols;  // -1 because you are using 1-based indexing. 
    }

    int row(int index) {
        assert index > 0 && index <= rows * cols;
        return (index - 1) / cols;
    }

    int index(int x, int y) {
        assert x >= 0 && x < cols && y >= 0 && y < rows;
        return y * cols + x + 1;
    }

    int[] neighbors(int point) {
        int x = col(point);
        int y = row(point);

        int[] result = new int[8];
        int cnt = 0;

        // go over possible neighbors and collect valid ones
        for (int ny = max(y - 1, 0); ny < min(y + 2, rows); ny++) {
            for (int nx = max(x - 1, 0); nx < min(x + 2, cols); nx++) {
                if (nx != x || ny != y) {
                    result[cnt++] = index(nx, ny);
                }
            }
        }
        return Arrays.copyOf(result, cnt);
    }
}

Board brd = new Board(4, 4);
int colOf7 = brd.col(7);  // 2  (0-based from left)
int rowOf7 = brd.row(7);  // 1  (0-based from top)
int[] neighborsOf7 = brd.neighbors(7);   // [2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12]
int index = brd.index(2,1); // 7 (1-based linear index)
```